# Postman returns 200 on API call, but cURL command returns 401

Tags: api, curl, iis, iis-8

I have a .Net API exposed, running on an IIS Server. There is a Windows scheduled task that executes nightly. It runs a cURL request. When I copy that command and execute it in a cmd window, it returns a 401.

I try the same api call in Postman, and get a 200.

[image]

IIS logs show:

> 2020-06-04 02:59:55 W3SVC3 127.0.0.1 POST
>   /api/tasks/checkstaledirectdebits - 443 - 127.0.0.1
>   PostmanRuntime/7.25.0 - - example.com 200 0 0 557

My cURL command is this:

> -X POST https://example.Com/api/tasks/checkstaledirectdebits -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H
>   "X-API-Key: MyValidKey" -H "Accept: *.*" -H
>   "Host: api.kikka.com.au" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H
>   "Content-Length: 0"

And IIS logs:

> 2020-06-04 02:58:37 W3SVC3 127.0.0.1 POST
>   /api/tasks/checkstaledirectdebits - 443 - 127.0.0.1 curl/7.59.0 - -
>   example.com 401 0 0 4640

Both the cUrl command, and the Postman instance are running on the server. The same one the API is running on. Am I missing something that Postman does, that I need to make cURL do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you generate an equivalent HTTP request by using `PostMan Code Snippet Genertator`. This could guarantee that these requests are absolutely in the same.
[image]
[image]
For more details check the below links.
[Converting a POSTMAN request to Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432735/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl)
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/
https://blog.postman.com/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/
Secondly, I doubt that there are some redirection operations occurred during the request resulting in the HTTP header(X-API-Key) lost, so that the authentication failed. Please carefully check the URL.
Here is a careless demonstration.
[HttpClient returns 401 with correct authorisation header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190930/httpclient-returns-401-with-correct-authorisation-header)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.